# Hadoop: Multinode cluster only recognizes 2 live nodes out of 3 data nodes

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, webhdfs

I have setup mutlinode hadoop with 3 datanodes and 1 namenode using virtualbox on Ubuntu. My host system serves as NameNode (also datanode) and two VMs serve as DataNodes. My systems are:

1. 192.168.1.5: NameNode (also datanode)
2. 192.168.1.10: DataNode2
3. 192.168.1.11: DataNode3

I am able to SSH all systems from each system. My hadoop/etc/hadoop/slaves on all systems have entry as:

```
192.168.1.5
192.168.1.10
192.168.1.11
```

`hadoop/etc/hadoop/master` on all systems have entry as: `192.168.1.5`

All `core-site.xml`, `yarn-site.xml`, `hdfs-site.xml`, `mapred-site.xml`, `hadoop-env.sh` are same on machines except of missing entry for `dfs.namenode.name.dir` in `hdfs-site.xml` in both DataNodes.
When I execute `start-yarn.sh` and `start-dfs.sh` from NameNode, all work fine and through JPS I am able to see all required services on all machines.

---

```
Jps on NameNode:
5840 NameNode
5996 DataNode
7065 Jps
6564 NodeManager
6189 SecondaryNameNode
6354 ResourceManager
```

---

```
Jps on DataNodes:
3070 DataNode
3213 NodeManager
3349 Jps
```

---

However when I want to check from     `namenode/dfshealth.html#tab-datanode` and          `namenode:50070/dfshealth.html#tab-overview`, both indicates only 2 datanodes.

tab-datanode shows NameNode and DataNode2 as active datanodes. DataNode3 is not displayed at all.

I checked all configuration files (mentioned xml, sh and slves/master) multiple times to make sure nothing is different on both datanodes.

Also `etc/hosts` file also contains all node's entry in all systems:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
#127.0.1.1      smishra-VM2
192.168.1.11    DataNode3
192.168.1.10    DataNode2
192.168.1.5     NameNode
```

One thing I'll like mention is that I configured 1 VM 1st then I made clone of that. So both VMs have same configuration. So its more confusing why 1 datanode is shown but not the other one.

Comment: what have you tried till now? Did you checked log for any exception? Did you tried restarting cluster?

Comment: I restarted VMs as well as host machine multiple times. At one point it showed my DataNode3 as active but then DataNode2 was missing. Which log file I should look into?

Comment: goto log directory, and do ls *data*

Comment: in hadoop-smishra-datanode-NameNode.log I found the only exceptio as :2014-10-12 17:31:08,687 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: IOException in offerService
java.io.IOException: Failed on local exception: java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer; Host Details : local host is: "NameNode/192.168.1.5"; destination host is: "NameNode":9000;

Comment: In hadoop-smishra-datanode-DataNode3.log I found this exception: 2014-10-12 03:21:28,271 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: DataNode3:50010:DataXceiver error processing unknown operation  src: /192.168.1.5:59441 dst: /192.168.1.11:50010
java.io.IOException: Version Mismatch (Expected: 28, Received: 18245 )
 at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.datatransfer.Receiver.readOp(Receiver.java:57)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataXceiver.run(DataXceiver.java:211)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: In yarn-smishra-nodemanager-DataNode3.log I found: 2014-10-12 03:00:38,194 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeStatusUpdaterImpl: Unexpected error starting NodeStatusUpdater
java.net.ConnectException: Call From DataNode3/192.168.1.11 to NameNode:8031 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused

Comment: No Almas... I couldn't get the reason. I am able to SSH from host to vms and vice versa, so couldn't get the reason for network issues. For version mismatch issue, my both VMs are Clones of each other. So why I am getting issue with only one VM?

Comment: I reconfirmed with Java -Version and Hadoop Version and both VMs are returning same values:
java version "1.7.0_65"
Hadoop 2.5.1

Comment: Please check for inbound security setting of cluster

Comment: Sorry but I am new to hadoop.. so can you please explain how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2014/01/how-to-create-a-simple-hadoop-cluster-with-virtualbox/

I'll bet that your problems come from the network configuration on your Virtual Box VMs. The post above has a lot of detail around how to ensure that the internal network between the VMs is set up correctly, with forward and reverse name resolution working, no duplicate MAC addresses, etc, which is critical for a Hadoop cluster to work correctly.